# Рандомный список

Tags: python, случайные-числа

```
return await msg.answer(
    'Приятного просмотра!',
     attachment=','.join(
         f"video{vid['owner_id']}_{vid['id']}"
             for vid in data["items"]
     )
)
```

Он берет с запроса как я понял самые первые. Как сделать что бы из 200 он выбирал рандомно а не по списку сверху?

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите проблему яснее

Comment: в .join выдается с начала списка и так по низу. А мне нужно что бы выдавалось рандомно из списка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модул `random`, функция `shuffle()` перемещает элементы списка рандомно на месте.   Пример:

```
import random

list_ = [1, 4, "a", True]
random.shuffle(list_)

print(list_)
```

Возможный вывод:

> ```
> [True, 4, 1, 'a']
> ```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Михаил, не стоит.

Answer (score 1):

Не забудьте импортировать библиотеку `random`

```
retun await msg.answer(
    'Приятного просмотра!',
     attachment=','.join(
         f"video{vid['owner_id']}_{vid['id']}"
              for vid in random.shuffle(data["items"])
     )
)
```

Comment: И вам спасибо большое